# Hibernate update @ManyToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, sql-update

I've a @ManyToMany relation mapped by `JOIN TABLE` like this

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CERTIFICADO_PAIS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CERTIFICADO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PAIS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    public List<PaisDTO> getPaisDTOs() {
        return this.paisDTOs;
    }
```

i want to update a collection via `SET` property in Hibernate Update statement.
the query is the following

```
String hql= "UPDATE CertificadoDTO certificado SET " +
                "certificado.paisDTOs = :paisDTOs " +
                "WHERE certificado.id = :idCertificado ";

Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
q.setParameterList("paisDTOs", certificadoDTO.getPaisDTOs());
q.setParameter("idCertificado", certificadoDTO.getId());
q.executeUpdate();
```

I dont want to update the parent entity(certificado) because i dont have all the information about the object filled in the object. I recover only the information needed depending where am i in my app.
So `certificadoDAO.update(certificado)` is not a solution.

I dont want to map the `JOIN_TABLE (CERTIFICADO_PAIS)` doing a 
@OneToMany - `JOIN TABLE` - @ManyToOne

Is a SQL query the solution? Is it possible to update a collection `SETTING` the property in latest versions of hibernate?

It was imposible for me to get information about this.

### Thanks!

**Aditional info**

```
hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl  - parse() - HQL: UPDATE es.aemps.certificados.dto.CertificadoDTO certificado SET certificado.paisDTOs = :paisDTOs0_, :paisDTOs1_ WHERE certificado.id = :idCertificado
```

**Error message**

```
hibernate.hql.PARSER  - line 1:101: expecting IDENT, found ':'
```

Comment: Your query is wrong, `q.setParameterList("",list)` is used if you are using `in query`

Comment: I've tried `(q.setParameter("paisDTOs",certificadoDTO.getPaisDTOs())`but I got another error. The main question is about if hibernate allows to update a collection with a hql query.

Comment: @BustakaS were you ever able to find a solution to this, or did you have to resort to native query?